# how do I figure out where a usb controller is in /dev?

Tags: linux, usb, dev

This is a linux question, how do I figure out where a usb controller is in /dev?

I have tried doing `ls /dev > before.txt ls /dev > after.txt diff before.txt after.txt` pluging the device in when I go to take the after text file. I still can not find the device.  dmesg reports:

```
[50276.080032] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
[50276.298047] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1430, idProduct=4748
[50276.298054] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[50276.298058] usb 5-1: Product: Guitar Hero X-plorer  
[50276.298061] usb 5-1: Manufacturer: RedOctane Inc(c)2006 
[50276.298065] usb 5-1: SerialNumber: 05D18E3
[50276.301272] input: RedOctane Guitar Hero X-plorer as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/input/input12
```

but I dont know where that is. how can I find this device?

Comment: Are you looking for a USB device or a USB (host) controller?  USB controllers do not have nodes in **/dev**, just like network devices (e.g. eth0) do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device has a name in */dev*, then 
the simplest answer, since you already have the *DEVPATH*, *i.e.* */devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/input/input12*, is to use *udevadm*:

```
udevadm info -q all /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/input/input12 | grep DEVNAME
```

Comment: And additionally, if the kernel doesn't recognize the device because there's no matching driver and/or nor matching udev rules, then there will be no device node (what is probably meant by "usb controller" in the question) in `/dev`.

Answer (score 0):

`lsblk` will provide you a nicer overview about your currently plugged in block devices. It reads the sysfs filesystem to get the information.

Comment: its not a block device, its a controller, (a character device). and lsblk shows nothing for it. (of course)

Comment: oh, right. please check if `lsusb`provide you the desired output.

Comment: lsusb doesnt show the file in /dev I also tried lsusb -v

Comment: I'm sure this should be helpful! http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144029/command-to-determine-ports-of-a-device-like-dev-ttyusb0